# Что может быть быстрее, чем math sqrt?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Передо мной стоит задача:
Мне необходимо максимально быстро найти количество целых квадратных корней из нескольких триллионов целых чисел, не превышающих *100 000^2*
Проще говоря:

100 = 10^2 - подходит

3 = не подходит

28 = не подходит

49 = 7^2 - подходит

...

и т.д.

В рамках поставленной задачи я использую директиву openMP, для равномерного распределения потоков между ядрами процессора, однако даже в таком случае скорость выполнения программы меня не очень устраивает.
В данный момент используемая мною конструкция выглядит так:

```
int y = sqrt(x);
if (y==int(y))
  i++;
```

Я пытался воспользоваться поиском во множестве SET, зная, что мое число никогда не будет превышать *100 000^2*

```
set<int> mySet;

for (int j = 1; j <= 100001; j++) 
    mySet.insert(j*j);

if (mySet.find(x) != mySet.end()) 
  i++;
```

Но этот способ оказался во много раз медленнее, чем обычное вычисление из под квадратного корня.
Подскажите, возможно ли с помощью средств языка еще как-то ускорить выполнение одной итерации или заменить вычисление из под корня чем-то более быстрым? Буду рад любым наводкам!

Comment: Несколько триллионов - это несколько тысяч секунд на обход этих чисел.

Comment: `10**10/8.0/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0 =
1.1641532182693481` то есть вместо дерева вы можете завести битовый массив на 1,16 Гб, в которым i-ый бит будет 1 если число i имеет целый корень и 0 - если не имеет. Тогда вам не нужно будет за logN искать в дереве, вам нужно будет только бит проверить (условно - за O(1), правда я не знаю как быстро будет проходить обращение к такому биту в оперативке)

Comment: Ответ : 100000 штук

Comment: @AlexGlebe у вас может быть несколько триллионов троек. В задаче нигде не сказано, что среди нескольких триллионов чисел встречается все числа от 1 до10^10. Так же там могут быть несколько триллионов девяток.

Comment: https://habr.com/company/infopulse/blog/336110/ - а это (или что-то подобное) не годится?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Есть очень эффективный способ ускорить вычисления - отбрасывания заведомо "не квадратов". Если вспомнить школьную математику, то можно догадаться, что последние n цифр квадрата числа зависят только от последний n цифр самого числа. Отсюда вывод - если число заканчивается на 0 1 4 5 6 9, то это может быть квадрат какого то числа. Если же 2 3 7 8 - то это точно не квадрат.

Но по последней цифре дает 40% отсеивания. Этого маловато. По последним двум цифрам (00 01 04 09 16 21 24 25 29 36 41 44 49 56 61 64 69 76 81 84 89 96 ) процент отсеивания уже 78%. А это очень хорошо. То есть, в 4 с 5 случаев даже вычислять ничего не нужно. Идем дальше. При последних трех цифрах уже можно отсеять 84.1%, 4 цифры 89.56 - а это очень и очень хорошо - на рандомных данных можно получить десятикратный прирост.

Сами данные можно хранить в небольшом массиве и вычислять при старте. Последние 3 цифры можно получать через `% 1000`.

Comment: Та же идея с байтами позволит обойтись без модуля (на 16-ричных цифрах можно показать, что последний ниббл может быть 1,4,9,0x10,0x19,0x24 etc)

Comment: я попробовал. Как то странно получается. последний байт - 82% отсечения, 2 байта - 83, 3 - тоже 83.

Comment: Да, забавно. По полубайтам (hex) `1: 0.25; и 2, и 3 и 4: 0.17; 5: 0.08; 6: 0.006 7:  0.00037; 8:0.0000233` - т.е. 3 байта (маска 0xFFFFFF) может быть относительно выгодно

Comment: Ага, эти доли зависят от диапазона  - я привёл для квадратов в диапазоне 10^10, а для 10^12 для трёх байтов доля меняется до 0.055, а для 10^14  сходится к тому же значению  около 1/6. Для десятичных цифр, кстати, те же яйца - 4 и 5 цифр дают примерно одно и тоже, 6 лучше.

Comment: если Вы берете последние три цифры, то не важно, прогоняете числа в диапазоне 0..999 или 0..99999.

Answer (score 6):

Я бы попробовал собственную реализацию с set на битовых масках.
Выделяем ~1.2 Gb памяти одним куском и устанавливаем в нем 100000 нужных бит.

Так как set будет сильно разряженным, то сначала проверяем что весь байт не 0, если это так - проверяем нужный бит.

Возможно обработка по 4 или 8 байт сразу будет быстрее чем по 1 байту.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы не тратить много памяти, создайте [фильтр Блума](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Это структура данных, позволяющая определить принадлежность элемента к множеству (в данном случае - множеству квадратов `1,4,9...10^10`).

У неё есть особенность - алгоритм может сообщить, что элемент присутствует в множестве, хотя на самом деле его нет - ложноположительное срабатывание.

В этом случае придётся проверить руками, извлекая корень. Однако для большинства чисел (доля ложных срабатываний зависит от выделенной памяти) такая проверка не нужна, т.к. ложноотрицательных срабатываний не бывает.

Пример на Delphi

```
var
  b: TSynBloomFilter;
  i, cnt: Integer;
  ii: Int64;
begin
  //выбираем 5xразмер словаря, больший размер уже не особо влияет на количество коллизий
  b := TSynBloomFilter.Create(500000);
  try
    //загоняем квадраты до 10^10
    for i := 1 to 100000 do begin
      ii := int64(i) * i;
      b.Insert(@ii, sizeof(ii));
    end;

    //считаем, сколько обнаружений выпало на диапазоне 10^8
    //истинных совпадений 10000
    cnt := 0;
    for i := 1 to 100000000 do begin
      ii := i;
      if b.MayExist(@ii, sizeof(ii)) then
          Inc(cnt);
    end;
     //через две секунды видим - 
    //получается, что потребовалось проверить 11359 чисел
    Memo1.Lines.Add(cnt.ToString);
  finally
    b.Free;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Идея с std::set хорошая, только вместо std::set надо использовать отсортированный массив квадратов, который сгенирировать скритпом, должно получится что-то типа:

```
const int64_t n2[] = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ... 100000^2 };
```

Далее используя бинарый поиск `std::lower_bound(n2, n2+size, testValue)` будешь быстро находить нужное значение (или не находить). Такой массив занимает всего 800kb легко влазит в кеш процессора

Comment: Тот же самый set, только оверхеда меньше. Там же тоже поиск за logN - ведь std::set - это сбалансированное бинарное дерево поиска.

Comment: Проблема в том что несколько триллионов раз будет вызываться либо поиск в дереве либо двоичный поиск  в массиве. Надо убрать O(logN) и получить O(1), чтоб прям хороший прирост в скорости получить

Comment: @vegorov O(logN) vs O(1) это понятно, но тут главная фишка, что этот массив не покидает кеш процессора, это может быть быстрее чем O(1) доступ в 1.2 GB

Comment: возможно. На массиве из 100000 элементов бинарный поиск сделает до 17 (или 16?) итераций

Comment: @vegorov это так, надо проверят. Например сортировка пузырьком, которая не покидает L1 кеш выигрывает у любой другой сортировки.

Comment: Кстати про кеши - иногда вижу вот эти вот отсылки к кешу процессора и быстроте - а как это делается ? Вы можете на C++ заставить процессор что-то выполнять на кеше? Ну в смысле какие-то данные класть в кеш, заместо других?

Comment: @vegorov нет, не могу, кеш на то и кеш, что процессор сам его заполняет и освобождает по необходимости. Если коротко, то процессор не работает с ОЗУ, чтоб что-то посчитать, надо сначало загрузить данные в регистры, делать это из кеша намного быстрее чем из ОЗУ. Если алгоритм "простой", то различные эвристики правильно угадывают что может понадибится и могут заполнить кеш процессора данными, которые им будут востребованны.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте целочисленный корень. Может быть будет быстрее, но я не верю.

```
# include <stdbool.h>
# include <stdio.h>

long isqrt(long ) ;
long isqrt(long num) {
    long res = 0;
    long bit = 1L << (sizeof(long)*8-2); // 2^62
    while (bit > num)        bit >>= 2;
    while (bit) {
        if (num >= res + bit) {
            num -= res + bit;
            res = (res >> 1) + bit;        }
        else            res >>= 1;
        bit >>= 2;    }
    return res; }

bool isSquare(long x) ;
bool isSquare(long x){
  long y = isqrt(x);
  //fprintf(stdout,"y = %ld\n",y);
  return y*y == x;}

int main(){
  long x;
  fprintf(stdout,"print number ?");
  fscanf(stdin,"%ld",&x);
  bool res = isSquare(x);
  fprintf(stdout,"result = %s\n",(res?"true":"false"));
  return 0;}
```